# SQL Select * from multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, pdo

Using PHP/PDO/MySQL is it possible to use a wildcard for the columns when a select is done on multiple tables and the returned array keys are fully qualified to avoid column name clash?

example:

**SELECT * from table1, table2;**

gives:

Array keys are 'table1.id', 'table2.id', 'table1.name' etc.

I tried "SELECT table1.*,table2.* ..." but the returned array keys were not fully qualified so columns with the same name clashed and were overwritten.

Comment: beware of identically named coluns in different tables - you'll only get one instance.

Comment: Yes. I did notice that if I knew the number of columns in each table I could retrieve values by the numeric index but thats not the case.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to do this?

It's usually a bad idea to use SELECT * from multiple tables anyway, so I'm just trying to figure out the thought process behind you doing this before I give you an answer.

Comment: Agreed. Unless you don't know the column names (and I bet you do), SELECT * is never a good idea: you're running two queries instead of one (one for the column names, then your query) and you're most likely bringing back more data than you need. Might not notice a problem now, but if some of those fields are BLOBs or have a lot of text, you will.

Comment: @Stephen I have several 'content' tables with unrelated columns and one 'metadata' table that holds similar data for the other tables. I query one content table with the metadata table (lets say one to one relationship) for all the content table columns. I wish could explain better but my database lingo is limited.

@Tom Of course I know the column names. Just don't want to type them out!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can. The easiest way is with pdo, although there's at least a few other extensions which are capable of it.

### [pdo](http://www.php.net/pdo)

Set the attribute on the [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) object, not the [PDOStatment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php).

```
$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES, true);
```

That's it. Then you get associative array keys like `$row['myTable.myColumn']`. It works if you fetch an object too (eg via `PDO::FETCH_OBJECT`) so beware, because you need to access the properties like `$obj->{'myTable.myColumn'}`

*The [manual says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) the `PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES` attribute is only supported by certain drivers. If the above doesn't work, this *might* work instead.

```
$pdoStatement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$pdoStatement->execute();
//build our associative array keys
$qualifiedColumnNames = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $pdoStatement->columnCount(); $i++) {
    $columnMeta = $pdoStatement->getColumnMeta($i);
    $qualifiedColumnNames[] = "$columnMeta[table].$columnMeta[name]";
}

//fetch results and combine with keys
while ($row = $pdoStatement->fetch()) {
    $qualifiedRow = array_combine($qualifiedColumnNames, $row);
    print_r($qualifiedRow);
}
```

---

Same basic pattern is used for other database extensions

### [mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
//build our associative array keys
$qualifiedColumnNames = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($res); $i++) {
    $columnMeta = mysql_fetch_field($res, $i);
    $qualifiedColumnNames[] = "$columnMeta[table].$columnMeta[name]";
}

//fetch results and combine with keys
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
    $qualifiedRow = array_combine($qualifiedColumnNames, $row);
    print_r($qualifiedRow);
}
```

---

### [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

```
$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
//build our associative array keys
$qualifiedColumnNames = array();
foreach ($res->fetch_fields() as $columnMeta) {
    $qualifiedColumnNames[] = "{$columnMeta->table}.{$columnMeta->name}";
}

//fetch results and combine with keys
while ($row = $res->fetch_row()) {
    $qualifiedRow = array_combine($qualifiedColumnNames, $row);
    print_r($qualifiedRow);
}
```

This should also work with table aliases (tested in php 7.1) - the qualified column name will use the table alias.

Comment: This is a great idea, unfortunately it does not get the table alias

Comment: @FullDecent both of the `PDO` methods, and the `mysqli` method I presented work properly for me with table aliases. I tested on php 7.1. I didn't test the `mysql` method because it's so old and unsupported now.

Answer (score 5):

you can do this:

```
SELECT Table1.*,Table2.xyz, Table2.abc,... From...
```

where you get all columns from one table using "*" and then just the columns from the other table you need, so there is no clash.

You could also use column aliases, where you "rename" a column:

```
SELECT Table1.A AS T1_A,Table2.A AS T2_A,... From...
```

your result set would be of columns T1_A and T2_A

Comment: Firstly you are specifying the column names - we don't know the columns and what if xyz or abc are also in Table1?. Secondly, as I said, I've tried the wildcard.

Comment: If we don't know the columns in the tables then its just a tad more difficult to rename them.

Comment: how can you not know the columns? is this generated with dynamic SQL? if so, dynamically build the select list.

Comment: The tables involved are dynamic. I'm trying to avoid writing code that handles each 'type' of table.

Comment: @zaf if you don't know the column names, how do you know which ones you need/ which ones are being overwritten?

Comment: @Tom And thats the puzzle. If the column name included the table name we would be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no; there is no SQL syntax for ensuring that column names are unique.

If you truly don't know the names of the columns and must use `SELECT *`, your only real option would be to revert to some very ugly looking dynamic SQL that could inspect the structure of the tables and generate a query that would select them all explicitly with a table-name prefix.

I don't know which RDBMS you're using, but something like this should work on SQL Server:

```
declare @columns table (idx int identity(1,1), tablename varchar(100), columnname varchar(100))

insert into @columns (tablename, columnname) 
select tablename, columnname

from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

where tablename in ('table_1', 'table_2')

declare @sql nvarchar(4000)

declare @i int
declare @cnt in

declare @col varchar(100)
declare @table varchar(100)

select @i = 0, @cnt = max(idx), @sql = '' from @columns

while @i < @cnt
begin
    select @i = @i + 1

    select @col = columnname, @table = tablename from @columns where idx = @i

    if len(@sql) > 0
        select @sql = @sql + ', '

    select @sql = @sql + '[' + @table + '].[' + @col + '] as [' + @table + '_' + @col + ']'
end

select @sql = 'select ' + @sql + ' from table_1, table_2'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: By the time I write that I could have written the sql queries by hand. Hang on... I could have done that instead of being here. Joking. I don't know which language/db/library but I do remember having to work with fully qualified column names and hating to type the full column name. Now I have the reverse problem.

Comment: @zaf: Then adapt it. What you're looking for isn't strictly possible. I've provided you with something that will at least *accomplish* what you're looking for, even if it's less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly repackaged from @goat:

```
// Workaround for setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES, true);
function pdoStatementExecuteAndFetchObjWithTableNames(PDOStatement $statement)
{
  $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
  $statement->execute();

  //build our associative array keys
  $qualifiedColumnNames = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < $statement->columnCount(); $i++) {
      $columnMeta = $statement->getColumnMeta($i);
      $qualifiedColumnNames[] = "$columnMeta[table].$columnMeta[name]";
  }

  //fetch results and combine with keys
  while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
      $qualifiedRow = array_combine($qualifiedColumnNames, $row);
      yield (object) $qualifiedRow;
  }  
}
```

NOTE: if you use:

> SELECT 1 FROM my_table AS my_table_alias

then you will get `my_table`. I would have hoped for `my_table_alias`. I got this result with PHP 5.6 and sqlite driver.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PHP (particularly the MySQL, PgSQL, MSSQL extensions) will always have your columns overwrite in the case of overlap.

I would recommend creating a `View` in your database, and Alias your columns so that they are "fully-qualified".

For example: (MySQL)

```
CREATE VIEW viewTable1Table2 AS
    SELECT
        t1.field1 AS Table1Field1
        t2.field1 AS Table2Field1
    FROM Table1 t1
        INNER JOIN Table2 t2
            ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

The syntax may not be perfect, but you can get a general idea of what I am talking about.

Comment: Didn't know about that but still the same problem.