# how to select all the data from many tables?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

how to select all the data from many tables?
i try

```
`"SELECT * FROM `table1`, `table2`"`
```

,
 but result none understandable for me. it returns only some rows from `table1`, and 3 times all the data from `table2`. i've red one same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523631/sql-select-from-multiple-tables), but don't understand the answer. so could you help me? thanks in advance.

### update:

when i try

```
(SELECT * FROM `table1`) UNION (SELECT * FROM `table2`)
```

it returns
**#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns**

Comment: Is there a relationship between table1 and table2?  Common column, etc?

Comment: You have to select the same number of items from table1 and table2 to use them in an union.

Try to :

SELECT a, b, c, d FROM table1 UNION SELECT a, b, c, NULL FROM table2

If table1 has more fields than table2, or viceversa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [UNION SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) construct

Answer (score 2):

By doing that select with the "," between 2 tables and no WHERE clause, you are doing an implicit [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#cross_join) of the 2 tables (all combinations of rows between the 2 tables). This is likely Not What You Want. See UNION, as mentioned by other answers.

Answer (score 1):

How do you want the data displayed? Are both tables of the same schema? If so you could use the UNION operator.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to show the data from many tables and there is no relationship between the data, you have to program logic instead of database logic.

show tables  (SQL command)
foreach result  (programming language of your choice)
  select * from tablename (SQL command)