# SQL problems - same field names in multiple MySQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, union

I have a keyword search that searches multiple DB tables for thumbnail images using UNION ALL. I have two pages, results.php, and view.php.  My goal is to able to click a thumbnail image on results.php and be directed to a larger version of that same image on view.php. The problem is each image in all my tables uses the field name "id" so when I click a thumbnail on results.php I get two different images with the same id from different tables.  I tried changing the id's to different names, but when it was time to pass url parameters I can only choose 1 value. (if you can choose more than 1 I don't know how).  So my question is why are my id's from different tables being grouped together, and how can I change this?

Image Results Page (which works perfect):

```
 SELECT *
    FROM table1
    WHERE keyword LIKE %colname% OR id  LIKE %colname%  
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM table2
    WHERE keyword LIKE %colname% OR id  LIKE %colname%
```

View Image Page (having problems here):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id = colname
UNION ALL
FROM table2
WHERE id = colname
```

Comment: Just to note, it isn't good practice to use `*` over naming all your columns, __even__ if you need all the columns returned.. :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to namespace your table field names:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = colname UNION ALL FROM table2 WHERE table2.id = colname
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a derived field to both of the subqueries, so you can figure out which table that particular row came from:

```
SELECT 'table1' AS source, *
FROM table1
...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table2' AS source, *
FROM table2
```

then have your code check that new 'source' field so you can point at the appropriate DB table later on when it comes time to display that image.

Of course, if both tables have an identical structure, that begs the question of why you didn't just combine them into a single table and add this 'source' field in this new "global" table, saving the trouble of having to run two queries to fetch image data.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget you can use the `AS` keyword to alias fields and tables

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 as t1
WHERE t1.keyword LIKE %colname% OR t1.id  LIKE %colname%  
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table2 as t2
WHERE t2.keyword LIKE %colname% OR t2.id  LIKE %colname%
```

Comment: I'm guessing we all got -1's because we answered the generic question instead of ranting about the design flaw; so much for providing answers/value to others browsing questions/answers or possibly stuck in someone ELSE's bad table design that they aren't allowed to alter.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, 1 as table_reference
FROM table1
WHERE id = colname
UNION ALL
select *,2
FROM table2
WHERE id = colname
```

Answer (score 0):

Your id's aren't being grouped together by mysql. It's just that you're requesting the database results as associative php arrays, with the column names as the array keys. You can't have duplicate array keys, so you only get one of the values.

If you don't need to know the name of the table, just fetch a numerically indexed array instead of associative array. If you need the table names, either modify your sql to alias the columns, or you can use more automated methods
[SQL Select * from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523631/sql-select-from-multiple-tables/2525396#2525396)

Answer (score 0):

1) If all your tables have the same structure,

## its a huge design flaw

and you ought to merge them in one table.

2) if your tables are different and you have to show only one image - what's the point in using union on the view page? if it's just one image from one table - why do you query 2 tables?