# MySQL return full table.column names

Tags: mysql

If I have a query thus:

```
SELECT id, name, age FROM people;
```

I will get columns named id, name and age. Is there an option to specify "I want full table.column names in my result"? IE, ideally I'd run the above query and get the columns people.id, people.name and people.age.

If it makes a difference, the query is being run from PHP.

I do not wish to use SELECT id AS `people.id` (etc) as I have around 50 queries containing around 10-12 columns each. I wish to avoid manually rewriting all these queries.

The 'duplicate' question has no answer for my issue (nor it's original question as far as I can tell) other than "it's not possible".

Comment: Duplicate of the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268296/have-mysql-select-statement-return-fully-qualified-column-names-like-table-field

Comment: Thanks Aditya. Looks like there was no solution there either :-(

Comment: Yes. Maybe it really isn't possible. I could suggest a way to avoid a lot of the manual work though. You could use Notepad++ to do a replace in All Opened Documents. :-)

Comment: I think that's really the only way. And it's going to be nasty... [sigh].

Comment: You can do it in PHP, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2525396/300224

Answer (score 0):

You can use column aliases for that purpose.

```
SELECT id AS 'people.id', name AS 'people.name', age AS 'people.age' FROM people;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm hoping to avoid. I have around 50 queries that I would need to manually fix and many of them contain a dozen columns.

Comment: Then I am afraid if there's any other way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `as`

```
SELECT id as `people.id`, name as `people.name`, age as `people.age` FROM people;
```

Try this.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm hoping to avoid. I have around 50 queries that I would need to manually fix and many of them contain a dozen columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...concat your table name with column_name and get all the column from your table using information schema.......

```
SELECT group_concat('table1.',COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table1';
```

later on if you want you can store that result in variable and use them as per your requirement.

rather you can create a dynamic query using input table name and db_name and traverse them until your goal reach :-)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not suitable. Some tables have a lot of columns and I need to only return the columns I'm displaying.

Comment: ok,are these column included in same order in every table ....then its not a big deal to retrieve that column using ther column_number /ordinal position in where condition

Answer (score -1):

Use Alias
Basically aliases are created to make column names more readable.
[Sql Aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Example :

```
 SELECT id AS 'people.id', name AS 'people.name', age AS 'people.age' FROM people;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm hoping to avoid. I have around 50 queries that I would need to manually fix and many of them contain a dozen columns.